# How to populate a dropdownlist in ASP.NET Core MVC from table?

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2019

I recently needed to start using Visual Studio again, but it has been over a decade since I've been in there and needless to say quite a bit has changed on me! I realize there are many similar questions, but I haven't been able to get any of them to work. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Here's the situation: I have a a shared search bar layout which currently runs a text search on title. It needs a dropdown for category which should compile from the Category1 table.

View (Trees/Index):

```
<form asp-controller="Trees" asp-action="Index" method="get">
    <p>
        Category: @*select tag here*@
        Title: <input type="text" name="SearchString" />
        <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
    </p>
</form>
```

Model (Category1.cs):

```
public class Category1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public byte Active { get; set; }
}
```

Controller (TreesController.cs):

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string searchString)
{
    var trees = from f in _context.Tree
                select f;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        trees = trees.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(searchString));
    }

    return View(await trees.ToListAsync());
}
```

I've removed everything I tried and reverted back to the base search functionality. Please let me know if you need more information of if I have been unclear. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi @UnofficiallyDan,any update about this case?

Comment: Does my solution work for you?

Comment: It works @Yinqiu, Thank You!
...but while I have your attention...
In my demo code I had this in the index controller, do you know how would set this up as a function I can reference on the other pages I require?

Comment: That is similar, you only need to use the code in the action you need: `ViewData["Category1"] = new SelectList(_context.Category1.ToList(), "Id", "CategoryName");` and then in your view Use `<select name="category1id" asp-items="ViewBag.Category1">
                 <option>Category1</option>
             </select>`

Comment: OK, I'm coming from a PHP mindset (which is what I primarily work in), so I was thinking I could wrap the viewdata variable in a function and then only have to reference it instead of writing out the whole block each time. E.g., `function getCat1(_context){return ViewData["Category"] = ...;}` and then only have to set `getCat1(_context);` in each controller block.

Comment: You can see my update answer.

Comment: Excellent, just what I was looking for! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your code like below:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string searchString,int category1id)
{
    var trees = from f in _context.Tree
                select f;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        trees = trees.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(searchString));
    }
    ViewData["Category1"] = new SelectList(_context.Category1.ToList(), "Id", "CategoryName");

    return View(await trees.ToListAsync());
}
```

View:

```
<form asp-controller="Trees" asp-action="Index" method="get">
<p>
    Category: <select name="category1id" asp-items="ViewBag.Category1">
                <option>Category1</option>
            </select>
    Title: <input type="text" name="SearchString" />
    <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
</p>
```

**Update:**

You can create a function like this:

```
public SelectList getCat1(ApplicationDbContext _context)
    {
        return (SelectList)(ViewData["Category1"] = new SelectList(_context.Category1.ToList(), "Id", "CategoryName"));
    }
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    getCat1(_context);
    return View();
}
```